# MS sql 2008 try catch still throws exception

Tags: sql, try-catch

I worried all day.
My label is very big -  '20317302009001'. 
Zlecenie is int column - so sql generates error when compare zlecenie=@label.
I tried to catch it, but still get message:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Procedure label_check, Line 9
>   The conversion of the varchar value '20317302009001' overflowed an int column.
>   Who knows the answer?
>   Thank you!

```
begin TRY 
if (@komponent is null) and ISNUMERIC(@label)=1  
 begin
  set @komponent=null
   if exists(select * from Rejestr_zuzycia_tkaniny where zlecenie=@label)
     begin
      declare @program int;
      select @program=program from Rejestr_zuzycia_tkaniny where zlecenie=@label
      select @komponent=komponent from Komponenty_programu where program=@program
     end;
 end; 
end TRY
begin CATCH
 set @komponent=null
end CATCH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you don't actually use `zlecenie` as a number, so you might want to compare by casting it as a `varchar` first like so:

```
if exists(select * from Rejestr_zuzycia_tkaniny where cast(zlecenie as varchar(20))=@label)
```

However, if you do need to process `zlecenie` as a number later on e.g. add it to something, then you might want to make it a `bigint` instead of `int` to accommodate large values.

MSDN has this to say about `TRY...CATCH` in T-SQL:

> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution.

I believe that the arithmetic overflow error might belong to the second scenario, which would explain why the `CATCH` block does not handle it. However, I have not been able to get any corroboration elsewhere so I suggest you do not just take my word for it.

Comment: Thank you! Your advice is very good. I still to try understand why it generates error when it is run in save "try-catch" clause

Comment: @Piotr I have updated my answer to try and address your query.